# Detect tap on a button in UITableViewCell for UITableView containing multiple sections in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

On UITableviewCell, I am trying to click on "AddToCart" button and by clicking on this immediately i am hiding the "AddToCart" button and showing the "+" and "-" buttons; It is working perfectly but unfortunately i see similar action happened on other cells as well due to this "AddToCart" button is hidden on 8th,15th,22nd row cells.

Could you help me to solve this.

```js
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

class ProductListScreen: UITableViewController {
    
    
    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    var tempProducts: [Product] = []
    var imagesurlslist = [String]()
    
    
    
    let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray)
    var products: [Product] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityIndicatorView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3);
        tableView.backgroundView = activityIndicatorView
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
         dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("xxxxx").child("0").child("xxxxxxx")
        dbRef.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshotAA) in
            for snapshotchild in snapshotAA.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let snapshotchildobj = snapshotchild.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let image:String  = snapshotchildobj?["imageurl"] as? String ?? ""
                let title:String  = snapshotchildobj?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let price:String  = snapshotchildobj?["price"] as? String ?? ""
                let units:String  = snapshotchildobj?["units"] as? String ?? ""
                let quantity:String  = snapshotchildobj?["quantity"] as? String ?? ""
                let quantityunits:String  = quantity + " " + units as? String ?? ""
                self.tempProducts.append(Product(url: image,title: title,price: price, quantity: quantityunits))
                self.imagesurlslist.append(image)
            }
            self.products = self.tempProducts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    var showImageIndex : Int?
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(products.count)
        return products.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    

        let product = products[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell",for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
        showImageIndex = indexPath.row
        cell.setProduct(product: product)
        let image = imagesurlslist[indexPath.row]
        cell.productImage!.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "xxxxxxxx"))
        
        cell.cartButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
        
        cell.tapCartButton = {
            print(indexPath.row)
            print(ProductCell().addtocartbuttonclicked)
            ProductCell().addtocartbuttonclicked = "Yes"
            
        }
        return cell;
    }
}





*******************************


import Foundation
import UIKit

class ProductCell: UITableViewCell {
    var index: IndexPath?
    var isAddToCartVisible: Bool?
    
    var addtocartbuttonclicked:String = "No"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productQuantity: UILabel!
    
    var tapCartButton: (() -> Void)? = nil

    let productImageView: UIImageView = {
        let productImage = UIImageView()
        productImage.image = UIImage(named: "xxxxxxxxx")
        productImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        productImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        productImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return productImage
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(productImageView)
//        ios 9 constraints
        productImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        productImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        productImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        productImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    

    
    func setProduct(product: Product){
        productTitle.text = product.title
        productPrice.text = product.price
        productQuantity.text = product.quantity
    }

    
//    **************** Objects Initialization ****************
    

    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var postiveButtonLabel: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var negativeButtonLabel: UIButton!
    
    
     @IBAction func positiveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("pblisterener clicked")
    let mystring = String(describing: (selectedQuantity.text)!).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let myInt1 = Int(mystring)
    print (myInt1!+1)
    selectedQuantity.text = " "+String(myInt1!+1)

}

@IBAction func negativeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("mbnlistener clicked")
    let mystring = String(describing: (selectedQuantity.text)!).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let myInt1 = Int(mystring)
    if(myInt1 != 1){
        selectedQuantity.text = " "+String(myInt1!-1)
    }
}
    
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedQuantity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cartButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBAction func cartClick(_ sender: Any) {
        addtocartbuttonclicked = "Yes"
        print(addtocartbuttonclicked)
        if( addtocartbuttonclicked == "Yes" ) {
        tapCartButton?()
        cartButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
        postiveButtonLabel.isHidden = false
        negativeButtonLabel.isHidden = false
        selectedQuantity.isHidden = false
        
        }
        addtocartbuttonclicked = "Yes"
    }
    
    
    

    

}



Please refer this Video for more Info : https://youtu.be/kUMLAmksr-w
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, This issue occurs because of "dequeueReusableCell". You can resolve it through using an extra variable(var isAddToCartVisible: Bool?) i.e defined in your product model, initial set all false for that, and when tap on any index path then set true for that product. if again facing the same issue then update here with your product's model. I will correct it.

Comment: Ashutosh, I am new to Swift, could you help me the above code for my need... Thanks so much in advance..

Comment: Hey, Is there any model implemented to get this data on the network call. If yes please share your model code, So that  I would update that model data and provide the solution. Also, update "cell.setProduct(product: product)"  function code in your question.

Comment: Ashutosh, I have updated my question with the complete code, I got stuck at here since 3 days , could you help me to solve this.. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: var products: [Product] = [] in this line you have used a structure/class of "Product", Could you please add those code here. I can understand the problem because I have to face the same

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll through a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`, those views will reuse the cells which disappear from the screen via `dequeueReusableCell` function call. That means that you should override or restore the states of those cells, because they won't be changed by table or collection views. This is best to be done by overriding `func prepareForReuse()` from the `UITableViewCell` where you should remove the states of that cell. In your case, you should hide the "Add To Cart" button and, also important, unset the `tapCartButton` closure (i.e. set it to nil, because it might cause a lot of trouble in the future).

This function will be called whenever that specific `UITableViewCell` will be reused by the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure needs a property where you track whether or not it has been "Added to Cart"

When you set your cell's data, show or hide the button:

```
func setProduct(product: Product){
    productTitle.text = product.title
    productPrice.text = product.price
    productQuantity.text = product.quantity
    
    // show or hide the add to cart button
    if product.isInCart {
        cartButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cartButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Then, in the closure you create in `cellForRowAt`:

```
    cell.tapCartButton = {
        print(indexPath.row)
        
        // this is wrong...
        // you create a NEW ProductCell and print the value of addtocartbuttonclicked
        //print(ProductCell().addtocartbuttonclicked)
        // then you create ANOTHER NEW ProductCell and set the value of addtocartbuttonclicked
        //ProductCell().addtocartbuttonclicked = "Yes"
        // closure ends, and your NEW ProductCell goes away
        
        // instead, you want to update your data
        // something like
        self.products[indexPath.row].isInCart = true
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**According to your code, I am Assuming your "Product" is something like:-**

```
struct Product {
    var url: String?
    var title: String?
    var price: String?
    var quantity: String?
    var isAddedInCart: Bool? // I have added extra varible to resolve your issue
}
```

**Now I have to Modify your existing code with the help of "isAddedInCart" variable trying to fix your issue.**

*Use it as follows:-*

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

class ProductListScreen: UITableViewController {


    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    var tempProducts: [Product] = []
    var imagesurlslist = [String]()



    let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray)
    var products: [Product] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityIndicatorView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3);
        tableView.backgroundView = activityIndicatorView
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
         dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("xxxxx").child("0").child("xxxxxxx")
        dbRef.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshotAA) in
            for snapshotchild in snapshotAA.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let snapshotchildobj = snapshotchild.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let image:String  = snapshotchildobj?["imageurl"] as? String ?? ""
                let title:String  = snapshotchildobj?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let price:String  = snapshotchildobj?["price"] as? String ?? ""
                let units:String  = snapshotchildobj?["units"] as? String ?? ""
                let quantity:String  = snapshotchildobj?["quantity"] as? String ?? ""
                let quantityunits:String  = quantity + " " + units as? String ?? ""
                self.tempProducts.append(Product(url: image,title: title,price: price, quantity: quantityunits, isAddedInCart: false))
                self.imagesurlslist.append(image)
            }
            self.products = self.tempProducts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }



    var showImageIndex : Int?
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(products.count)
        return products.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let product = products[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell",for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
        showImageIndex = indexPath.row
        cell.setProduct(product: product)
        let image = imagesurlslist[indexPath.row]
        cell.productImage!.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "xxxxxxxx"))

        cell.cartButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.tapCartButton = {
            print(indexPath.row)
            print(ProductCell().addtocartbuttonclicked)
            ProductCell().addtocartbuttonclicked = "Yes"
            product.isAddedInCart = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
        return cell;
    }
}





//*******************************


import Foundation
import UIKit

class ProductCell: UITableViewCell {
    var index: IndexPath?
    var isAddToCartVisible: Bool?

    var addtocartbuttonclicked:String = "No"

    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productQuantity: UILabel!

    var tapCartButton: (() -> Void)? = nil

    let productImageView: UIImageView = {
        let productImage = UIImageView()
        productImage.image = UIImage(named: "nammadukhaninkannada")
        productImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        productImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        productImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return productImage
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(productImageView)
//        ios 9 constraints
        productImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        productImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        productImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        productImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }



    func setProduct(product: Product){
        productTitle.text = product.title
        productPrice.text = product.price
        productQuantity.text = product.quantity
        if product.isAddedInCart == true {
           cartButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
           postiveButtonLabel.isHidden = false
           negativeButtonLabel.isHidden = false
           selectedQuantity.isHidden = false
        }
        else{
            cartButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
            postiveButtonLabel.isHidden = true
            negativeButtonLabel.isHidden = true
            selectedQuantity.isHidden = true
        }
    }


//    **************** Objects Initialization ****************




    @IBOutlet weak var postiveButtonLabel: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var negativeButtonLabel: UIButton!


    @IBAction func positiveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }


    @IBAction func negativeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var selectedQuantity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cartButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBAction func cartClick(_ sender: Any) {
        addtocartbuttonclicked = "Yes"
        print(addtocartbuttonclicked)
        if( addtocartbuttonclicked == "Yes" ) {
        tapCartButton?()
        }
        addtocartbuttonclicked = "Yes"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ashutosh, It works perfectly.. I am seeing similar issues for "+" and "-" buttons, nevertheless i will implement the same logic for these as well.. Once again Thanks alot.

Comment: Ahutosh, I need one more help from you, now i am seeing similar issue with Positive and Negative button , I am able to see increment decrement is happening with the two buttons, but it is reflecting on buttons of other cells. By default i am showing the quantity as "1" when i click on "AddToCart" from there it behaves according to Positive button and negative button Note: I have updated my code for positive and negative button in the code itself, could you help me regarding this.. Thanks so much in Advance..

Comment: Similar to "AddedInCart" variable make one variable of "numberOfProduct" and assign 1 to all of the product. And when you update your product quantity then update the model value for the same and reload your table.